# Eclipse claims it is missing a required library - but I think its already included

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

Eclipse is telling me in the "Problems" window that it is missing required library:

```
'c:\[long path omitted]\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar'
```

but I already have GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar in the project's "libs" directory.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you add the jar to the build path? Right-click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Libraries -> Add JARs... -> select the jars and hit ok

Comment: Thank you - that's the right answer - I had thought that putting the jar file in the libs directory was all that was needed. Put it as an asnswer and I will give you the tick.

Comment: @mick I believe on the latest sdk version all you need to do is drop your jar files in the libs folder and they'll automatically be included as part of the build

Comment: I now suspect that what happened is that I specified a particular location for the jar using java build path and that file is no longer there. Later on I learned the trick of just putting files in the libs directory - but the java build path data was still being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

check twice your project's build path, event in lib/ the file has to be specified as dependency